# Video player skips on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: video, dvd

If I use the seek button when playing videos in the default video player, it continues to play, but the screen gets stuck on the same place and after a long time (10 min), it will go some other place and play. Is this a bug, or is there a video player that can play videos properly?

Comment: Which player are you using? Try vlc.

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC. It always works in Windows, and ever since I switched to Linux it has still worked flawlessly: http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-install-vlc-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you installed all the Codecs necessary to read commercial dvd. Because, I use Totem and everything works fine, as well as VLC. Here are the command lines that may help you.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```